# KVM Switch - takes forever to recognize HDMI input for 1 of my laptops?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, switch, kvm-switch

I have this KVM:
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B08H4FKJPN/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1

My KVM and laptops works with my previous monitor, my **BenQ 1080 60hz monitor**:
https://www.amazon.ca/BenQ-GW2480-Brightness-Intelligence-Flicker-Free/dp/B072XCZSSW

Recently replaced my BENQ with a **1440p 144 hz Gigabyte M27Q** (I downscaled it to 60hz just for my KVM; i also know the M27Q have their own KVM, I plan to use it for my 2nd laptop!):
https://www.amazon.ca/Gigabyte-Monitor-Display-Response-FreeSync/dp/B08JWCHR5N

My KVM works immediatley if I plug it in with my **Dell XPS 13 laptop** (smaller laptop):
https://www.dell.com/en-ca/shop/dell-laptops/xps-13-laptop/spd/xps-13-9310-laptop

**Problem:**
My KVM takes ~30 seconds to switch to  **Lenovo Flex 5** (larger laptop). It is super slow and I'm wondering what the fix for this is?
https://www.amazon.ca/Lenovo-Graphics-included-81X20005US-Graphite/dp/B086226DDB

Any ideas what's up? the KVM does not like my new 1440p 144hz monitor I think and that's where the problem lies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have edited my post, hopefully, it clear things up @Community